# Phonegap Calender sheduler not allowing create event with double click

Tags: cordova, calendar, double-click, touchscreen, dhtmlx-scheduler

I'm working on a Calender scheduler using dhtmlx in phonegap.I managed to get the events from my mysql database but unable to create new events because the double click event in a touch screen enable to zoom-in or zoom-out.
Please help me in this.how to disable this zoom-in and zoom-out and enable create event.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special, touch version of dhtmlx scheduler - http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_mobile.shtml.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the viewport meta tag? If not, try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Thanks.This disables the zoom-in from my device

Answer (score 0):

Probably scheduler do not recognizes a touch device, when rendered in a PhoneGap.

Try enabling touch support mode manually

```
scheduler.config.touch = "force";
```

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_touch_config.html